# What data to collect when conducting a research on aphasia?

Tags: research

What data to collect when conducting a research on aphasia??

I am trying to do a research in psycholinguistics and I don't know where to start and what data to collect.

I am really confused and I need your help soon.

Thank you

Comment: I checked scholar.google.com for aphasia. Check out the test manuals or examination booklets, and I'm certain you'd find what others have used for aphasia.

Comment: look at references in [Goldrik (201x)](http://faculty.wcas.northwestern.edu/matt-goldrick/compass.pdf) for examples of experiments with aphasics. Write to any of the scholars you see listed and most will be kind enough to write you back with advice.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to gather information on aphasia, you'll have much more luck consulting the literature of Speech/Language Science or Neuropsychology than you will in the Linguistics literature.   Speech/Language Sci departments & Neuropsychologists educate not only the neuropsychologists & speech/language therapists who assess and treat aphasia but also most of the scientists who do aphasia research.

a.   Examples of relevant journals:

Advances in Speech-language Pathology

American Journal of Speech-Language Pathology

Canadian Journal of Speech-Language Pathology and Audiology

International Journal of Speech Language Pathology

Journal of Medical Speech-Language Pathology

Journal of Speech and Language Pathology, Applied Behavior Analysis

Journal of Speech, Language, and Hearing Research

Language and Speech

Topics in Language Disorders

b.   If you have lots of money, the pricey online "Aphasiology" journal may be useful:  http://www.psypress.com/journals/details/0268-7038/

c.   Here's a guide to Aphasia research:  https://www.aphasia.org/?q=content/research-guide

d.   Most hospitals have speech/language therapists on staff, and some are Ph.D.'s in this field.

e.   Here's a list of books and articles about aphasia at Questia:   http://www.questia.com/library/science-and-technology/health-and-medicine/diseases-and-disorders/aphasia

f.   Don't forget the Psychology Wiki.  http://psychology.wikia.com/wiki/Special:Search?search=aphasia&fulltext=Search&ns0=1&ns14=1

g.   Here's an introduction to the subject:   http://www.medicinenet.com/aphasia/article.htm

I'm sure there are more resources for you to find.   Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much for this useful info, it really helped.